# Symmetric Encryption By Key Behavior

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012

I've just run the following test and I am deeply confused:

I created a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[enxtest](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cleara] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [encrypta] [varbinary](2000) NULL,
    [clearb] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_enxtest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I've populated it with data like so:

```
id | cleara        | encrypta | clearb
1  | teststring!1  | NULL     | NULL
2  | teststring!1  | NULL     | NULL
3  | teststring!2  | NULL     | NULL
4  | teststring!2  | NULL     | NULL
```

I ran a script to encrypt the contents of cleara, one at a time using a SQL Server symmetric key and certificate pair like so (relevant code only, sproc internals) and insert the encrypted value into the encrypta field:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY THIS_IS_THE_KEY
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE THIS_IS_THE_CERT
CONVERT(varbinary(2000), EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('THIS_IS_THE_KEY'), cleara), 1)
```

Then we deleted the database master key, the symmetric key, and certificate and recreated them, giving them the same name they had before.  I ran a script to decrypt the varbinary similarly to the encrypt code above and inserted that into clearb.

This query gives me the following results:

```
SELECT id, cleara, clearb
FROM enxtest;

id | cleara        | encrypta | clearb
1  | teststring!1  | NULL     | teststring!1
2  | teststring!1  | NULL     | teststring!1
3  | teststring!2  | NULL     | teststring!2
4  | teststring!2  | NULL     | teststring!2
```

Questions:

1. How is this possible?  I was expecting to get clearb == clearb but
   clearb != cleara.  I hoped that switching the keys out would produce
   consistently incorrect varchar values.
2. Is there a way to restore a backup to another server, while leaving the        binary data in the tables untouched, creating new keys that will reliably decrypt that data to consistent but incorrect (vs. the original clear text value) values?

Edit: Here is the full script we ran, in batches.

```
--Batch 1
declare @e1 varbinary(2000);
declare @c1 varchar(50);
select @c1 = cleara from enxtest where id = 1;
exec dbo.spEncryptString @cleartextString = @c1, @encryptedString = @e1 OUTPUT;

declare @e2 varbinary(2000);
declare @c2 varchar(50);
select @c2 = cleara from enxtest where id = 2;
exec dbo.spEncryptString @cleartextString = @c2, @encryptedString = @e2 OUTPUT;

declare @e3 varbinary(2000);
declare @c3 varchar(50);
select @c3 = cleara from enxtest where id = 3;
exec dbo.spEncryptString @cleartextString = @c3, @encryptedString = @e3 OUTPUT;

declare @e4 varbinary(2000);
declare @c4 varchar(50);
select @c4 = cleara from enxtest where id = 4;
exec dbo.spEncryptString @cleartextString = @c4, @encryptedString = @e4 OUTPUT;

update enxtest
set encrypta = @e1
where id = 1;

update enxtest
set encrypta = @e2
where id = 2;

update enxtest
set encrypta = @e3
where id = 3;

update enxtest
set encrypta = @e4
where id = 4;


/*
--Batch 2
drop symmetric key THIS_IS_THE_KEY;
drop certificate THIS_IS_THE_CERT;
drop master key;

create master key encryption by password = 'somepassword';
create certificate THIS_IS_THE_CERT with subject = 'subject' expiry_date = '20161231';
create symmetric key THIS_IS_THE_KEY with algorithm = AES_256
    key_source = 'source' identity_value = 'identity' encryption by certificate THIS_IS_THE_CERT;
*/

--Batch 3
declare @e1 varbinary(2000);
declare @c1 varchar(50);
select @e1 = encrypta from enxtest where id = 1;
exec dbo.spDecryptString @encryptedString = @e1, @cleartextString = @c1 OUTPUT;

declare @e2 varbinary(2000);
declare @c2 varchar(50);
select @e2 = encrypta from enxtest where id = 2;
exec dbo.spDecryptString @encryptedString = @e2, @cleartextString = @c2 OUTPUT;

declare @e3 varbinary(2000);
declare @c3 varchar(50);
select @e3 = encrypta from enxtest where id = 3;
exec dbo.spDecryptString @encryptedString = @e3, @cleartextString = @c3 OUTPUT;

declare @e4 varbinary(2000);
declare @c4 varchar(50);
select @e4 = encrypta from enxtest where id = 4;
exec dbo.spDecryptString @encryptedString = @e4, @cleartextString = @c4 OUTPUT;

update enxtest
set clearb = @c1
where id = 1;

update enxtest
set clearb = @c2
where id = 2;

update enxtest
set clearb = @c3
where id = 3;

update enxtest
set clearb = @c4
where id = 4;

--Check
select * from enxtest;
```

Comment: That seems strange. Do you have a full repro script?

Comment: I do, I'll post an edit in the morning.

Comment: @BenThul I've added the full script we ran, divied up into batches.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you actually trying to do? Dropping and re-creating keys is not something that you'd normally do if you want to recover/decrypt your data. If you want a one-way function, I'd suggest a hash! :)

Comment: @BenThul Trying to find an easy to fuzz sensitive data when we restore production to our dev/test environments.  I wanted to just swap the keys instead of producing new garbage data for testing and then encrypting with the new key.  I suppose there is header data in the ciphertext that specifies which key which was used and only that key can decrypt it at all.  I gave up and wrote a fuzzer yesterday anyways, thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quite produce a repro script (for example, I don't have the body of your stored procedure), but I see the problem. When you create a symmetric key with the same `KEY_SOURCE` parameter, you're essentially creating the exact same key. Once you know that, the fix is easy - provide a different value for `KEY_SOURCE` each time you create the key.